# @OneToMany relation in Ebean

Tags: java, ebean, relationships, activator

I'm trying to write a system which contains people and applications. Every person can apply for different applications.

I'm trying to apply a `@oneToManyRelation` on the person object (when retriving a person from the db, I would like to recive a list with every aplication that they applied for).

Here is my code:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="t_person")
public class person extends Model {
    @id
    @column(name="PERSON_ID")
    private string ID;

    more properties...

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=application.class, mappedBy="SOLDIER_ID")
    private ArrayList<application> ApplicationList;

    public ArrayList<application> getApplicationList() {
        return ApplicationList;
    }

    public void setApplicationList(ArrayList<application> applicationList) {
        ApplicationList = applicationList;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="T_APPLICATION")
public class application extends Model {
        @Id
        @Column(name="APPLICATION_ID")
        private int Id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
        private person Person;
}
```

I'm using Activator and an Oracle DB.  When I retrieve an application I get the person object ok, but when retriving a person, the application list is null.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem.
the problem is that applicationList is an ArrayList<> and not a List<>.
as soon as i change the ArrayList to a List. it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mappedBy` on your annotation for reverse attributes; it's not the column name you should use here but the name of the attribute on other object.

On Person:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
ArrayList<Application> applicationList;
```

On Application:

```
@ManyToOne
Person person;
```

You may need to add `@JoinColumn` where applicable. As said in comments, `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` shoudl help too.

Comment: thanks fot the answer, i changed to the attribute on other object and still nothing, it's returning null

Comment: updated my answer with eager fetch as specified in a (deleted ?) comment

Comment: @user2332718 it would be nice to update your question with what you tried exactly. I notice your code format is pretty weird (not following any know java formatting convention) it might just be a upper/lowercase issue.